# Creating a white frame around buttons

Tags: android

I'm a bit new to Android app develoment. I'm trying to create the following layout:

[image]

As you can see we have a background, two buttons and another white "background" which is the "frame" of the buttons. This frame is white and you can see the background fuzzy.

In the following image I surrounded the "white" part with a black frame so it will be easier to understand (because the background is a bit bright):

[image]

Please notice that this frame is not fully white (you can see the background though it).

I know how to add a background and create those buttons but how can I create that white frame?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the buttons in a `CardView` and set `app:cardCornerRadius` and `app:cardElevation` attributes.

Control the surrounding area with the margin of the `LinearLayout` that holds the buttons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button 1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button 2" />
    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I see the border, but how do I add that "white" outer/inner background glow?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a drawable like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="YOUR_BACKGROUND_COLOR"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
            <stroke android:color="YOUR_FRAME_COLOR" android:width="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

and apply this drawable as background to the root layout.